# Steam thinks it's running in compatibility mode

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I tried to start up Steam, but it says it is currently set to run in compatibility mode. I checked under Properties but compatibility mode is not enabled. I looked at settings for all users, but compatibility mode wasn't enabled either. Thinking it got fixed, I tried to start up Steam again but it still thinks it's set to run in compatibility mode. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open your Start Menu and enter `regedit` in the search bar.
2. Go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\AppCompatFlags/Layers`
3. Find the registry for `steam.exe` and delete it.

This should fix your problem.